# How to find Topic IDs in a CHM file

Tags: c#, chm

I want to open a CHM file from my C# project. I want to open the relevant section of the CHM file, thus I use the following code line

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, help_file, HelpNavigator.TopicId, topic_id);
```

The problem is, I don't have the source of the CHM file and I don't know the topic IDs of it. Is there a way to get the topic IDs of this CHM file?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440868/help-file-topic-id

Comment: @User yes, the same question. But it was not answered too. I don't have the source code of the CHM project. Is there a way to explore the topic ids of a chm file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of topics from a chm file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276019/get-a-list-of-topics-from-a-chm-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Extract the CHM with one of the various extracters (mostly chmlib based), and then look into the extracted "*.hhc" file. This is an topic map that matches topic tiles/ids to urls internal in the CHM file.

Note some rare CHM files have a binary TOC and no hhc file, but chances on that are very low, since HH defaults discourage it.

**Added later:**
The number of extraction options of the Free Pascal *chmls* tool have been updated. (though some are more of a dump functionality than real extraction): Make sure you get one from 2.6.4+

```
 list        [section number]
            Shows contents of the archive's directory
 extract      [saveasname]
            Extracts file "filename to get" from archive "filename",
            and, if specified, saves it to [saveasname]
 extractall  [directory]
            Extracts all files from archive "filename" to directory
            "directory"
 unblockchm  [filespec2] ..
            Mass unblocks (XPsp2+) the relevant CHMs. Multiple files
            and wildcards allowed
 extractalias  [basefilename] [symbolprefix]
            Extracts context info from file "chmfilename"
            to a "basefilename".h and "basefilename".ali,
            using symbols "symbolprefix"contextnr
 extracttoc  [filename]
            Extracts the toc (mainly to check binary TOC)
 extractindex  [filename]
            Extracts the index (mainly to check binary index)
 printidxhdr 
            prints #IDXHDR in readable format
 printsystem 
            prints #SYSTEM in readable format
 printwindows 
            prints #WINDOWS in readable format
 printtopics 
            prints #TOPICS in readable format
```

Comment: thanks, I got the hhc file. It's a Sitemap HTML. There are items like: `<UL>
<LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
<param name="Name" value="Produktübersicht"></param>
<param name="Local" value="37161011467/37161015563.htm"></param>
<param name="FrameName" value="_self"></param>
<param name="ImageNumber" value="1"></param>
</OBJECT>
</LI>`

Should topic id be here defined?

Comment: There now is also some option for that in chmls see above.